# Stop ActiveX control from giving focus to its form on MouseMove

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, activex

I am using a number of 3rd party ActiveX controls on my form. My application has multiple forms, and say these ActiveX controls are on `myAxHostingForm`. Moving the mouse over some of the controls gives `myAxHostingForm` focus. I want to stop this.

I have tried an empty event handler

```
For Each c In Me.ChildControls(Of AxHost)() ' custom extension method returning controls of type provided
    AddHandler c.MouseMove,
        Sub(s As Object, m As MouseEventArgs)
        End Sub
Next
```

I get the following exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException was caught
  HResult=-2146233067
  Message=Event MouseMove is not valid on this ActiveX control.
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.add_MouseMove(MouseEventHandler value)
       at <my source code file>
```

I'm hoping someone who knows something about ActiveX hosting in .NET can help make sense of this error, and possibly solve this annoying problem.

Edit:
Trying @Hans approach,

```
<ComImport, InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), Guid("00000114-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")>
Interface IOleWindow
    <PreserveSig>
    Function GetWindow(ByRef hwnd As IntPtr) As Int32
    Sub ContextSensitiveHelp(ByVal fEnterMode As Int32)
End Interface

Class ActiveXWindow
    Inherits NativeWindow
    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(m)
        If (m.Msg = &H200) Then Return
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Sub
End Class
```

this is inside my form load:

```
Dim itf = CType(CCDimage1.GetOcx, IOleWindow)
Dim hWnd As IntPtr
Dim hr As Integer = itf.GetWindow(hWnd)
If hr <> 0 Or hWnd = IntPtr.Zero Then Throw New Exception("Could not find handle for DataRay window")
Dim wrapper = New ActiveXWindow()
wrapper.AssignHandle(hWnd)
```

I get the exception on the first line:

```
System.InvalidCastException was caught
  HResult=-2147467262
  Message=Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Instruments.IOleWindow'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{00000114-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
  Source=Instruments
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ActiveX controls on the native window have handles which are different from the ones seen at Form_Load. So I wasn't able to ignore mouse movement on them explicitly. However, they are the only controls I want to ignore mouse movement for in my application, and they all share the characteristic of `Control.FromHandle(m.HWnd) Is Nothing = true`. Thanks @Idle_Mind for leading me to this approach.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Application.AddMessageFilter(New MouseMoveFilter())
End Sub
```

...

```
Public Class MouseMoveFilter
    Implements IMessageFilter
    Private Const WM_MOUSEMOVE As Int32 = &H200
    Public Function PreFilterMessage(ByRef m As Message) As Boolean Implements IMessageFilter.PreFilterMessage
        Select Case m.Msg
            Case WM_MOUSEMOVE
                Return Control.FromHandle(m.HWnd) Is Nothing 
        End Select
        Return False
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another approach you can try using IMessageFilter:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Load += Form1_Load;
    }

    void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // list out your 3rd party ActiveX controls here:
        Control[] controls = new Control[] { 
            this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1, 
            this.axWindowsMediaPlayer2 
        };
        Application.AddMessageFilter(new MouseMoveFilter(controls));
    }
}

public class MouseMoveFilter : IMessageFilter
{
    private const int WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x200;

    private List<IntPtr> ControlHandles = new List<IntPtr>();

    public MouseMoveFilter(Control[] controls)
    {
        foreach(Control ctl in controls)
        {
            this.ControlHandles.Add(ctl.Handle);
        }
    }

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
                if (this.ControlHandles.Contains(m.HWnd))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this method and the handles when passed to PreFilterMessage are different from the handles passed to the constructor from FormLoad

Comment: Well..you could try switching it up and pass in the controls themselves, then grab the current Handle() in PreFilterMessage()?

Comment: Hm, m.HWnd is still different from the handle of the control I had stored. Maybe this has to do with what Hans was saying about the handle of the control on the native window vs the AxHost wrapper window

Comment: That's very possible.  Sorry it didn't work for your situation.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, that doesn't work.  ActiveX controls create their own window and can party on it as they see fit.  Messing with you own app as well, it is rather an excellent malware injection vector.  They are supposed to play nice and work with the host but corners are cut frequently.

The only thing you can do is sub-class their window so you'll get a crack at their messages first.  First thing you need is to obtain their window handle, that requires using IOleWindow::GetWindow() method.  You'll need this declaration:

```
    [ComImport, InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), Guid("00000114-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
    interface IOleWindow {
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetWindow(out IntPtr hwnd);
        void ContextSensitiveHelp(int fEnterMode);
    }
```

Then you need to derive your own class from NativeWindow so you can override the WndProc() method and detect the messages.  A simple one that filters WM_MOUSEMOVE:

```
    class ActiveXWindow : NativeWindow {
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(m);
            if (m.Msg == 0x200) return;
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
```

Then you need to put this in place.  You have to wait until the native window is created, the form's Load event is normally the right time for that.  I used Windows Media Player to test the code:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var itf = (IOleWindow)axWindowsMediaPlayer1.GetOcx();
        IntPtr hWnd;
        int hr = itf.GetWindow(out hWnd);
        if (hr != 0 || hWnd == IntPtr.Zero) throw new Exception("Oh, no");
        var wrapper = new ActiveXWindow();
        wrapper.AssignHandle(hWnd);
    }
```

Comment: Hey Hans (I'm not the original question asker), why can't we use `axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Handle`?  It appears to work for me trapping and suppressing WM_MOUSEMOVE using IMessageFilter.

Comment: Because that's the AxHost wrapper window handle, not the native window that's inside of it and was created by the ActiveX control.  IMessageFilter does work for the messages that go on them message queue, like WM_MOUSEMOVE, since it is still the Winforms message loop that dispatches messages.  It won't work for sent messages, only sub-classing can do that.

Comment: When creating a new instance of my form with the Ax control on it, I get this exception: (see my edited question)

Comment: That's an exception raised in the form's constructor.  A million miles away from the Load event where I recommended you put the code.  It doesn't have anything to do with this answer.  Quacks like cut/paste problem.  First make the form work without the code.  Then add it.

Comment: Yes... I realized I defined the interface before the form's class def. and VB didn't like that. Now a new exception inside Form_Load.

Comment: That's a show-stopper, it doesn't implement IOleWindow.  Very strange, unless you murdered the IOleWindow interface declaration somehow.

Comment: just put that in my question as well

Comment: Hans, what do you mean by "very strange"? *Should* the Ocx implement `IOleWindow`? And if it doesn't what does that mean? Thanks for your help and insight.

Comment: Yes it does, AxHost does not support windowless ActiveX controls.  Absolutely no idea why it won't work for you.  I can't help you.